# Garage door opener with Santa Fe XL

Tags: hyundai, santa-fe, homelink

I bought `Chamberlain 1.25 HP Belt Drive MyQ Smart Garage Door Opener with Corner to Corner Lighting` and have it installed and working fine. 
I have a Hyundai Santa Fe XL 2017 with built-in homelink buttons. I tried to press learn button and program the button in the car. Tried with pressing the button in the remote and then the button in the car, nothing works.

Does anyone know how to program the car buttons with this garage door opener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chamberlain provides Homelink programming instructions for specific makes and models.  Just go to https://bridge.chamberlain.com/

According to the site, you don't need any special bridge and Homelink should work out of the box.  However, it's a bit more than just "pressing the learn button."    I've summarized the steps below, but for full details, visit their site at the link referenced above.

> #### Programming Instructions
>
> 1. Press and hold the two outer HomeLink® buttons, releasing only when the HomeLink indicator light begins to flash after 20 seconds.
> 2. Position the hand-held transmitter 1-3 inches away from the HomeLink surface
> 3. Using both hands, simultaneously press and hold both the desired HomeLink button and hand held transmitter button. DO NOT release until
>      the HomeLink indicator light flashes slowly and then rapidly.
> 4. Press and hold the trained HomeLink button and observe the indicator light.
>
>    - If the indicator light is solid/continuous, training is complete and your device should activate when the HomeLink button is pressed
>        and released.
>    - If the indicator light blinks rapidly for 2 seconds and then turns a solid/continuous light, proceed with the following training
>        instructions for a rolling code device.
> 5. At the receiver (motor head unit), locate the “learn” or “smart” button .
> 6. Press and release the “learn” or “smart” button; there are 30 seconds in which to initiate the next step.
> 7. Press and hold the trained HomeLink button for two seconds and release. Repeat the “press/hold/release” sequence up to 3 times to
>      complete the training process.